# Facebook: How to get fanpage by domain search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would love to get the Facebook fanpage for a domain with the Facebook Graph search.

I tried the following, but only got a random id but not the pages id?
https://graph.facebook.com/?domain=stackoverflow.com

Question:
How to get the Facebook Pages Name or ID when i only have the url to query for?
Does the id from the above graph search help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this the Graph API search:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&q=stackoverflow.com

Comment: no unfortunately i can't https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&q=newyork.com < example

Comment: You can't find `newyork.com` because they don't have a Facebook page.

Comment: why do i get a result right here: https://graph.facebook.com/?domain=newyork.com. The problem with your query is that it also would find domains like "notstackoverflow.com" ;)

Comment: Your query is getting a Facebook ID for the Open Graph object associated with their website. Try visiting the ID returned by your query. https://www.facebook.com/344798241148 And yes, there is no guarantee that the Graph API will actually make it *easy* to get what you need.